# Cross-matching streets with district

Tags: database, excel, function

I'm trying to make database in Microsoft Excel, and format it so I can use it for managing orders by the street and district. In first two columns I have my "Database", all the streets and matching districts for them. 
Third and fourth column should work in the way that if I enter street in 4th column, Excel matches it with the right district in the 3rd column.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yg6yuko.png]

Comment: if you want a database, why aren't you using Access?

Comment: Hey, yes, sure, that was first thing on my mind too, but because of some limiting factors, I can use only Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `=VLOOKUP(E2;A:B;2;FALSE)` in D2. Drag to fill the rest of the D column.